# Python. Django - Как сделать сохранение файла из формы на сервер

Tags: python, django, python-3.5, fileupload

Есть задача сделать загрузку xlsx- или csv-файла на сервер с помощью Django с дальнейшем чтением этого файла. Однако не получается сделать это через класс Forms

```js
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.views.generic.base import View
from django import forms
import xlrd

class UploadFile(forms.Form):
    user_file = forms.FileField(label='Выберите файл')
    
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'file_upload' in request.POST:
        upload_form = UploadFile(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if upload_form.is_valid():
            save_path = '/home/association_project/app/media/'
            user_file = upload_form.cleaned_data['user_file']
            upload_form.save()

            rb = xlrd.open_workbook(save_path + user_file, formatting_info=False)
            sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
            row = []
            for i in range(10):
                r = sheet.row_values(i)
                row.append(r)
            print (row)
            df = pd.DataFrame(row)
            df.columns = df.iloc[0]
            df = df.reindex(df.index.drop(0))
            print(df)

    else:
        upload_form = UploadFile()
       
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'upload_form': upload_form, 'fields_form': fields_form})
```

Ошибка в строке upload_form.save() `'UploadFile' object has no attribute 'save'`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, рабочий код для этой проблемы. Как сохранять файл из формы на сервер?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: сработало это https://www.journaldev.com/22467/django-modelforms